# local variable referenced before assignment in python 3.2

Tags: python, list, function, variable-assignment, python-3.2

The original code:

```
>>> def calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList):
    ctLowShelfLife = 0
    for number in shelfLifeList:
        if number <= 7:
            ctLowShelfLife += 1
    return ctLowShelfLife
>>> shelfLifeList = [5, 7, 10]
>>> lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLife)
```

When I try to run python 3.2 gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLife)
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in calcItemsLowShelfLife
    for number in shelfLifeList:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your indentation is off, and also I don't know what `ctLowShelfLife` is?

Comment: fixed! count low Shelf Life, count how many products have a shelf life of 7 or less days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare variable `ctLowShelfLife =0` before the loop begins.

**UPDATE**

The problem is with your indentation.
Your code should be like this ,

```
>>> def calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList):
    ctLowShelfLife = 0
    for number in shelfLifeList:
        if number <= 7:
            ctLowShelfLife += 1
    return ctLowShelfLife

>>> shelfLifeList = [5, 7, 10]
>>> lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList)
>>> lowShelfLife
2
>>>
```

Comment: on my shell it prints 7

Comment: @user3311946 can you please post your code about what you are exactly trying in shell >?

Comment: @user3311946 Again problem is with your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable before make `+= 1`:

```
ctLowShelfLife = 0    

def calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList):
    global ctLowShelfLife
    for number in shelfLifeList:
        if number <= 7:
            ctLowShelfLife += 1
    return ctLowShelfLife

shelfLifeList = [5, 7, 10]
lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList)
print(lowShelfLife)
```

If you declare `ctLowShelfLife` as global, you have to tell the function that you want to use the global variable.

If you don't want to use global, you can make it like:

```
def calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList):
    ctLowShelfLife = 0  
    for number in shelfLifeList:
        if number <= 7:
            ctLowShelfLife += 1
    return ctLowShelfLife

shelfLifeList = [5, 7, 10]
lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList)
print(lowShelfLife)
```

Comment: I did, just forgot to post it, sorrry!

Comment: The code I wrote works in my ubuntu with python3, did you check indentation?

Comment: i tryed global, but my professor doesnt like and when I tryed to run it closes python

Comment: I edit my answer. I tried both solutions in windows 8 with python3.3 and work ok

Comment: My mistake was here:
lowShelfLife = calcItemsLowShelfLife(shelfLifeList), i was using shelfLife instead of shelfLifeList. Thank you